# Circle-like parametrization of closed curves.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Can every closed, smooth, non-intersecting curve in the plane be parametrized as

\begin{align}
x(t)=a\cos\alpha(t),\:\:\:y(t)=b\sin\alpha(t),
\end{align}

being $a$ and $b$ constants and $\alpha(t)$ a continuous function such that $\cos\alpha(0)=\cos\alpha(L)$ and $\sin\alpha(0)=\sin\alpha(L)$, with $L$ *some* parameter ?

Comment: No those equations will only ever parametrise an ellipse.

Comment: .... nor a square.

Comment: @Callum True. There was a mistake in the last phrase. Now it should look ok at least for the case of the ellipse.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork For a square one simply takes $\alpha(t)$ either $0$ or $\pi/2$ along the respective segment. Anyhow, there is not continuous parametrization of a square or rectangle, so let's rule out non smooth boundaries.

Comment: @DanielKatzner I think you misunderstand. That isn't the problem. If a and b are constants then those equations will always trace out an ellipse changing $\alpha$ will only change how quickly we are travelling around that ellipse and changing $L$ will only change how much of a curve we draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the range of $\alpha$, this can only parametrise an ellipse, or part of an ellipse. To realize this, you just need to note that, with such a representation, you have that
$$
\frac{x(t)^2}{a^2} + \frac{y(t)^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
Were you maybe thinking of
$$x(t) = a(t) \cos t, \quad y(t) = b(t) \sin t \quad ?$$

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of $a$ and $b$ as constants. Because, if arc-length parametrized, the unit tangent to a curve can always be written as $(-\sin\theta(s),\cos\theta(s))$, then I wonder if not in its the tangent but in the curve itself a similar parametrization can be done.

Comment: Such a parametrization you propose, with $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ can indeed describe any closed curve ?

Comment: @DanielKatzner well at that point they can describe any closed curve at all. The sin and cosine parts are then effectively irrelevant.